# Link List Add elements in recursion language C

Tags: c, list, recursion, hyperlink

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodeNum
{
    int num;
    struct nodeNum *next;
} t_nodeNum;


// Functions declaration  ----------------------------
int menu();  // display menu and return choice

t_nodeNum* addition(t_nodeNum *node, int n);

void print_list(t_nodeNum *node);
// ----------------------------------------------------

// Main program to test link list functions
int main()
{
    int choice;

    t_nodeNum *pnode = NULL;
    t_nodeNum *head = NULL;
    t_nodeNum *temp = NULL;

    int numAdd = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int first = 1;

    do
    {
        choice = menu();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Please enter number : \n");
                scanf("%d", &numAdd);
                if (first)
                {
                    pnode = (t_nodeNum *)malloc(sizeof(t_nodeNum));
                    if (pnode == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("\n Error in allocation\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }

                    pnode->num = numAdd;
                    pnode->next = NULL;
                    first = 0;
                    head = pnode;
                }
                pnode = addition(pnode, numAdd);
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                printf("\n Print List: ");
                print_list(head);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (choice != 5);

    return 0;
}

// function menu display menu and return choice
int menu()
{
    int choice = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Please choose option to do: \n");
        printf("1. addition\n");
        printf("2. deletion\n");
        printf("3. search\n");
        printf("4. print\n");
        printf("5. exit\n");
        printf("\n option = ");

        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 5);

    return choice;
}

// function addition to add item to linked list in recursion
t_nodeNum* addition(t_nodeNum *p, int numAdd)
{
    int len = 0;

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        p = (t_nodeNum *)malloc(sizeof(t_nodeNum));
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Error in allocation\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        p->num = numAdd;
        p->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p = addition(p->next, numAdd);
    }
    return (p);

}

// function print_list to print linked list in recursion
void print_list(t_nodeNum *head)
{       
        printf("%d    ", head->num);
        if (head->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n");
            return;
        }

        print_list(head->next);

}
```

There is problem with the addition function it does not work correctly to add new item to the linked list and I does not know what is wrong please help
After adding new items and do print list it display only the first item

Comment: Recursion is the wrong way to go.  What if you have 10,000 nodes?  The stack memory used would be huge.   Iterate the list with a pointer.

Comment: @SteveWellens All recursion here is tail recursion, isn't it?

Comment: There are three cases that need to be handled: `p==NULL`, `p->next==NULL`, and `p->next!=NULL`.

Comment: @Rhymoid In this case recursion is recursion.   It is a bad way to solve this problem.

Comment: @SteveWellens The tail recursion in `addition` and `print_list` can be transformed into simple loops by any decently implemented tail call optimiser. There are no performance problems with this code. The only thing that might be wrong with it is the readability, but that's very subjective; if it's used very consistently across a codebase, I'd be all for it. The other remaining problem would be that it doesn't follow the MISRA C guidelines, but those are woefully outdated and therefore irrelevant.

Comment: @Rhymoid  Why don't you ask some other developers if they think it is a good idea to use recursion to iterate a linked list?

Answer (score 0):

In you `main` function  -

```
 pnode = addition(pnode, numAdd);
```

instead of `pnode` you need to pass `pnode->next` -

```
 pnode = addition(pnode->next, numAdd);
```

Problem with first call is that `pnode` is not `NULL` so it just adds new element at head position replacing previous value and returns.

Therefore, new node is not being created.

Comment: Hello I try your suggestion and I changed in main to                            pnode = addition(pnode->next, numAdd);  but it does not fix the problem there is something else that still buggy !!!